# bone getting far away when make cyclic extrapolation "repeat with offset"

Tags: animation, armature, graph-editor

i don't know how to make the suitable title for my problem here, sorry for that..

the problem is appear when i add F-modifier cyclic (shift E) extrapolation to all bone and make it "repeat with offset" in 3 bone (foot IK L, foot IK R, Torso)

but the foot IK_R have an error that make it stretch or getting far away as the animation getting longer. i think it's due to the y location however i can't trace or even fix the error..

Here is the blend file:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very old question but I had the same problem in Blender 4.

The final position minus the distance traveled of the bone has to equal zero. Otherwise the difference accumulates.

For example, if your path bone starts at `Z == 0` and you translate it to `Z == 4`, any other bone you translate in the Z direction must also be translated by 4 units Z. Bones that aren't translated must go back to their original position.